# Keyframes don't work correctly in IE11

Tags: html, css, css-animations, internet-explorer-11

I have a selection box animation where the selection box gets highlighted. Apparently, the keyframes animation works properly in Chrome but doesn't work properly in IE11.
I would like to know what should I change in the code so that it will also work in IE11.

```css
.animate-box{
    height: 100%;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
      -moz-animation-name: changeShadow;
      -webkit-animation-name: changeShadow;
      -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
      -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
@-webkit-keyframes changeShadow{
  from {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #90a4b2;
  }

  to {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #337ab7;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes changeShadow{
  from {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #90a4b2;
  }

  to {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #337ab7;
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="animate-box">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What happens in IE? [It seems to be supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes).

Comment: my mistake,I forgot to add animation attribute to css. close this issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the unprefixed properties for CSS Animation for IE10+, check it out on [CanIUse?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation). Also, you could use shorthand [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation) property:

```css
.animate-box {
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: changeShadow 0.5s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: changeShadow 0.5s infinite alternate;
    animation: changeShadow 0.5s infinite alternate;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
@-webkit-keyframes changeShadow {
  from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #90a4b2; }
  to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #337ab7; }
}

@-moz-keyframes changeShadow {
  from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #90a4b2; }
  to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #337ab7; }
}

@keyframes changeShadow {
  from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #90a4b2; }
  to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #337ab7; }
}
```

```html
<select class="animate-box">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks sergey Denisov

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I forgot to add animation property to css and include unprefix keyframes:

```
.animate-box{
    height: 100%;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-name: changeShadow;
    -webkit-animation-name: changeShadow;
    animation-name: changeShadow;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

@keyframes changeShadow{
  from {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #90a4b2;
  }

  to {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #337ab7;
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll also need to include the unprefixed `keyframes`. By the way, you could use the [`animation` shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation) here to reduce the amount of code needed: `animation:changeShadow .5s infinite alternate;`.

Comment: thanks for quick reply